# Location of colorscheme-files in Kate

Tags: kde, colors, syntax-highlighting, kate, color-management

In **Kate** one can export file `Fortran.katehlcolor` which store the information about color in syntax-highlighting.
The syntax-highlighting files itself are located in `~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax` which can be backuped easily.

Is there an analog directory for the `colorscheme`-files which already exists before exporting all `.katehlcolor`-files by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Kate keeps only user customized/modified color schemes in:

```
~/.kde/share/config/katesyntaxhighlightingrc
```

You have to export the get complete definitions.

Comment: Is there a way to automatize this in a Shell-script or something else?